# Windows keyboardhook reporting everything twice

Tags: delphi, winapi, hook

I am using Delphi and trying to read from a bar code scanner over USB, so that it is just another Human Interface Device.

I get the digits correctly, but get each twice. I imagine that this is key down and key up.

I could; kludge it with a flag and ignore very second read, but would rather do it propery.

My code is adapted slightly from [this link](http://delphi.about.com/od/windowsshellapi/a/keyboard_hook.htm).

Can I specify that I only want key_up events when assigning the hook?

```
KBHook := SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD,
                           @KeyboardHookProc,
                           HInstance,
                           GetCurrentThreadId()) ;
```

or somehow check a flag within the hook function itself?

---

Update:  I tried to code for it, but looks like I got it wrong. Here's what I tried at the start of my hook function

```
// http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644984%28v=vs.85%29.aspx
if Code < 0 then  
begin
   Result := CallNextHookEx(KBHook, Code, WordParam, LongParam);
   Exit;
end;

if (((LongParam and $80000000) <> $80000000)    (* key is not being released *)
and ((LongParam and $40000000) <>  $40000000))  (* key was not previously down *) then
begin
   Result := CallNextHookEx(KBHook, Code, WordParam, LongParam);
   Exit;
end;
```

---

[Further update] Five years after, and this still doesn't help, but I find that my original [follow-up question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9865990/why-does-my-keyboard-hook-receive-the-same-key-up-and-key-down-events-multiple-t) (q.v) does.

Comment: Did you get this working? If not, can you give details about the scanner?

Comment: +1 sorry, I was away on business. Will check on Monday. I guess it has  to do with me also checking the previous key state - which is probably not necessary when reading from a bar code scanner.

Comment: Lolx!! Five years later, I have the same problem. Google & find a question which perfectly matches my current problem - and it is my question!  Thanks, Jim for the answer.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In your KeyboardHookProc, you need to check the high bit of the **LongParam** argument. If the high bit is zero, it is a key press. If the high bit is one, it is a key release.

For example:

```
KeyUp:boolean;

KeyUp := ((LongParam and (1 shl 31)) <> 0);
```

Comment: +1 , I use `(lparam and $80000000)=$80000000` for detect `WM_KEYUP`

Comment: +1 Yup, I thought so. Looks like I coded it wrongly. Please see update to question above